# MacBook Windows shift on external monitors after Catalina upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, display, catalina

I have 2 external monitors connected to my MacBook pro (15-inch), one horizontal, one vertical if that's relevant. They worked perfectly before. Since upgrading to Catalina, whenever I unlock it after being away from it for a while, I have to re-arrange all the previously opening windows. They would sometimes scatter around, or shift to the right edge of their previous desktops, or other desktops of the same monitor or another, almost not visible. I continuously googled to see if anyone else is having this problem but didn't see any. Anyone has experienced the same? and is there anything I can do to prevent this annoyed behavior from happening?

Also asked [here](https://superuser.com/q/1496788/250250), no response so far.

Comment: I have noticed something similar with my Mac Mini, when waking from sleep there are some windows that are so the far to the right of the desktop that only a sliver of them are visible.